# C++ how to detect whitespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am creating a program that allows users to key in their user name and password. the problem is, when the system prompts to "Enter userName:" and I hit enter key, it will print out "Name cannot contain a blank"

but if I hit a FEW spaceBars and hit enter key and make it blank field after that ,it skips to prompt the user to enter the password without printing out "Name cannot contain a blank" and prompting the user to enter the userName again.

how should I change my codes to ensure that it will still prompt the user to enter the userName again even though I hit a spacebars and hit enter? please advise. thanks

code

```
string userName=" ";
string password;
cout << "Enter UserName:";

while (getline(cin, userName)) {
    if (userName.empty()) {

        cout << "Name cannot contain a blank."<< endl;
        cout << "Enter userName:";
        userName = userName;
        //throw errorMsg;
    } 

    if(!userName.empty()) {
        cout << "Enter Password";
    }
}
```

Comment: One would be to initialize an `istringstream` from the line, then slurp a `std::string` from it. It better be non-empty and the extraction better be successful. But regardless, just for clarity, is a username now allowed to have *any* whitespace? I.e. "John Smith" would not be valid, but "JohnSmith" would be (obviously)? Or are you only trying to protect against a username that was *only* whitespace?

Comment: I am trying to protect against username that has only whitespaces

Comment: I somewhat suspected that. Then what I mentioned above will work. I can post it as an answer with a sample snippet if you need it. Note, however, it will only read the first name of a two-name entry. Its a little more complicated to strip leading and trailing whitespace, then seeing if you have anything left over. But in reality, it *is* a username. All you should *have* to do is test if *everything* is whitespace (or empty), and if it is, re-prompt.

Comment: hi there, appreciate much if you could post a sample snippet answer. thanks

Comment: OK. posted. Don't forget to up-vote any answers you find useful, and always mark whatever answer is the best choice for your purpose (not just mine, anyone's that best fits your problem). Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username validation is not trivial, for many reasons. You don't want to be in the business of manufacturing what you "think" the user wanted to type, while at the same time it is clear you want to avoid a potentially long validation of what is *going* to be invalid.

In the end, I would suspect you can simply take the prospect entry, strip all the whitespace, and if there is anything left over, submit *the original entry* for validation. Don't bite off the business of validating something the user *may* have meant to type. I.e.

```
"\t\t   "
```

should be grounds for a re-prompt, while

```
"John Smith"
"\t WillJohnson "
"Gary"
```

should all be submitted *verbatim*, and let the chips fall where they may.

That said,

```
bool isValidUserName(std::string name)
{
    name.erase(std::remove_if(name.begin(), name.end(),
      [](char c){ return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));}), name.end());
    return !name.empty();
}
```

should do that for you. A sample is below:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isValidUserName("\t \t ") << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isValidUserName("\t Will Johnson ") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
false
true
```

Comment: This does not exactly check the validity of the username, but rather removes the spaces in a given string. It forces the username to be valid in some way.

Comment: Also, I think that `[](char c){ ...` is wrong you must specify at that point a predicate. At least for me this didn't compile! So, I changed is by creating a method `bool isSpace(char c)`, which was simply a wrapper on `std::isspace()`.

Comment: @ipinak perhaps a mundane question: does your toolchain support lambdas? I ask because that compiles on *both* my VS2012 and clang 3.4 rigs. If there is an error on your toolchain I'm curious what it is.

Comment: I have clang 3.2, so that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a C++11 compliant compiler your test for spaces could be using [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
 if (std::find_if(userName.begin(), userName.end(), isspace))
      != userName.end())
```

or

```
 if (std::find_if(userName.begin(), userName.end(), 
     [=](char c){return isspace(c);}) != userName.end())
```

Notice that several characters are space-like `' '` but also `'\t'` (tabulation) etc...

Comment: Whatever, there's `find_if`... And I thought my solution was clever... :P

Answer (score 1):

just consider the space as a character and increment it when you find it

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to check if the starting character of the username is a blank space and also the last slot of the string is not a blank space.
 example :
 This should be accepted = "a b".
 But
 this should not be   " a ".
 or this should not be  "  a".
 or this should not be  "a  ".

```
if (userName[0]!=" " && userName[userName.size()]!=" "){
       //accept this case and move on.
}
else{
         //reject all other cases.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;    

int main(){
    string username, password;
    int un = 1;
    int ps = 1;
    while(un){
    cout<<"Username:";
    getline(cin,username);
    int usize = username.size();
    vector <string> v ;
    v.insert(v.begin(), username);
    if (usize==1){
        if(username==" "){
            cout<<"Username can not be blank"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            un=0;
        }
    }   
    else{
        int check=0; int trim = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<usize; i++){
            if (username[i]!=' '){
                check=1;
                trim = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(check==1){
            un=0;
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    }

    while(ps){
    cout<<"Password:";
    getline(cin,password);
    int usize = password.size();
    vector <string> v ;
    v.insert(v.begin(), password);
    if (usize==1){
        if(password==" "){
            cout<<"Password can not be blank"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            ps=0;
        }
    }   
    else{
        int check=0;
        for (int i=0; i<usize; i++){
            if (password[i]!=' '){
                check=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(check==1){
            ps=0;
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Username is: "<<username<<endl;
    cout<<"Password is: "<<password<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the string is empty if so then do the empty validation
2. If the string is not empty then check if it has spaces i.e **find_first_not_of("\t ")** if this returns number greater than 0 we know the username has leading white/tab spaces followed by zero or more characters. i.e leading spaces then the username
3. Its upto you to now do the validation for a good username.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstring>

   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       string userName = " ";
       string password;
       cout << "Enter UserName:";


       while(getline(cin, userName)) {
           if(userName.empty()) {
               cout << "Empty String";
           } else if(userName.find_first_not_of("\t ") > 0) {
                   cout << "Could contain spaces followed by username or just spaces";     
           } else {
               cout << "User Name is Valid";
           }
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```